# PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM in DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Tags: paypal

I can't find a way to receive PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM (or PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM) in DoExpressCheckoutPayment reply as described in https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

Is mandatory to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails (I'm using "useraction=commit")? In documentation seems not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well. If you supplied the `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM` request parameter in your `SetExpressCheckout` operation, then the response from the `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` will return the `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM` value.

Answer (score 0):

I read again the documentation and in DoExpressCheckoutPayment is possible to *send* the PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM, for receiving it calling GetExpressCheckoutDetails is mandatory